# Remove padding in spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

Hello how can i remove this padding in spinner item? And how to remove underline? My code you can saw below. 
[image: myImage]

```
 <LinearLayout
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <TextView
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="DETERGENT"
         android:id="@+id/textView"
         android:gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
         android:textSize="14dp" android:textStyle="bold"/>
     <Spinner
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="36dp"
         android:id="@+id/spinner_detergent"/>
```

Java code:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, spinnerArray);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinnerDetergent.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Spinner_item.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

     <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="dfdfdf"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"/>
```

Comment: spinner and textview are in different layout ?? or in same layout ? if in same than put your signal XML file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi If you want to remove that line you can write a background. For that you simply place an image in the drawable and set that by using below tag.

```
android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
```

or

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

And the second one is your given spcific height. so remove that and give wrapcontent or try for small heights. Then that space will goes.

Comment: thank you, when i set transpanent background line and padding disappeared

Answer (score 0):

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner); 

//simple_spinner_item Specify the spinner TextView

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                    R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

// simple_spinner_dropdown_item Specify the dropdown item TextView if not set , and the same as simple_spinner_item  
     adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```